# Unable to Upload image through ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am uploading an image through CKEditor first time But it showing a blank iframe. Nothing showing in chrome console. Please help me in this issue.

```
            <textarea class="form-control-textarea" style="height: 600px" id="course" name="course"></textarea>

        <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('course', { filebrowserUploadUrl: 'ck_upload.php', filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
      });
      </script>
      <script>


<?php

//upload.php

if(isset($_FILES['upload']['name']))
{
 $file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
 $file_name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
 $file_name_array = explode(".", $file_name);
 $extension = end($file_name_array);
 $new_image_name = rand() . '.' . $extension;
 chmod('uploads', 0777);
 $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "gif", "png");
 if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension))
 {
  move_uploaded_file($file, 'uploads/' . $new_image_name);
  $function_number = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'];
  $url = 'uploads/' . $new_image_name;
  $message = '';
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($function_number, '$url', '$message');</script>";
 }
}

?>
```

[image: Check the image for error]

Comment: What does the error shown on the "blank" frame say? (underneath the sad paper)

Comment: This looks like a browser security issue. Check the errors in Chrome or FF development  tools.

Comment: @Jamie_D same thing iin internet explorer and firefox

Comment: on ckeditor, just add the image link/directory and then submit. it will be uploaded automatically